# Typescript in Firebase functions Error: Cannot find module, Failed to generate manifest from function source:

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, tsconfig

Typescript project in my Firebase functions app is unable to find module through `baseURL` in `tsconfig.json`

Here is the folder structure

```
|   package.json
|   tsconfig.json
|               
\---src
    \---Main
            main.ts
    |   
    \---Commons
            utilities.ts
    |   
    \---lib
        //where the compiled .js files are
```

Here is the code in `main.ts`

*I am trying to import `Commons/utilities.ts`*

[image]

As shown in the image, second line, The module path is well resolved and recognized by `visual studio code`, it even auto-suggests files from there. But the problem arises during typescript compilation

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "test/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

It throws error showing it is unable to find the module. This only happens when I import using the `baseURL` instead of relative path `.../Commons/utilities`

```
Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error: Cannot find module 'Common/utilities'
```

How can I fix this error to be able to use `baseURL` in my typescript files?

Comment: You can remove this behavior with mapping paths to you tsconfig.json file like

**"paths": {
   "@lib/": ["src/lib/"],
   "@common/": ["src/Commons/utilities/"]
}**

then instead of relative path .../Commons/utilities you can use just @common/{file_name}